# Write-protect an USB key as a DVD

Tags: security, usb, key

I need to write-protect an USB key. Many keys have lock to do this, but my need is to use the key as a DVD, i.a.

- copy files on the key
- lock the key
- distribute the key
- be assured that a customer with the key has the file I put on it.

I think the surest way is to hard-protect the writing (NTFS rights aren't enough as Linux users may overpass it), but a simple lock can be switched by anyone.

Does any one know a secure way?

Comment: No idea at all ? This is not possible ?